# Skim/Preview : forward sync not working

Tags: preview, macvim, skim

I am using `Skim` to preview pdfs generated by `vimtex` plugged into `MacVim` via `vim-plug` on MacBook Air M1.

Whenever I write any changes to my `.tex` files the pdf opened in Skim does get updated but the display page doesn't move to the updated location. I have set `Sync` options to `MacVim` and enabled `Check for file changes` and `Reload automatically` options in the Preferences.

Can someone help me by suggesting how to reload pdfs to correct page?

Alternatively, I tried using `Preview` but it doesn't even auto-reload until I move focus back to the opened pdf on it. I will be okay with whichever of the two can be made to work properly.